# ASP.NET - how to use CSS to align ASP.NET controls in a data entry situtaion?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a standard data-entry type form built in ASP.NET. I am pretty green with CSS and am trying to line up the labels and text fields on the form.

I am using the standard ASP.NET controls.

I know from my CSS book and web sites that I could use the label for="" with the name of an input text box to follow and float the labels but I don't how to do this with ASP.NET controls.** This is what I am trying to work with:

```
<div class="spacer1em"></div>
<div><span>Hotel:</span> <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" /> <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMap" runat="server">Map</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div><span>Address:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" /></div>
<div><span>Address:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress2" runat="server" /></div>
<div><span>City:</span> <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" /> <span>State:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" /> <span>Zip:</span> <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" /></div>
<div><span>Country:</span> <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" /></div>
<div><span>Phone:</span> <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" /> <span>Fax:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtFax" runat="server" /></div>
<div><span>Type:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtType" runat="server" /></div>
<div><span>Comments:</span> <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" /></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the method I use.

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="label"> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblHotel" Text="Hotel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtHotel" />:
  </div> 
  <div class="value"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" /> 
  </div> 
</div > 
<style type="text/css">
    .row { clear: both; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 5px 0; } 
    .label { float: left; text-align: right; margin-right: 10px; width: 150px; } 
    .value { float: left; text-align: left; } 
</style>
```

Comment: Shoot! I screwed this up! I don't need both Spans and ASP.NET Labels. They are supposed to be spans and ASP.NET textboxes with each row the labels and the textboxes aligning. I'll rewrite the question.

Comment: I rewrote the question but nothing needs to change except using the textbox instead of the asp label. It works! Thanks!